# Spring - transactional tests with transactional controller

Tags: java, spring, testing, transactions

I'd like to write integration tests for my application, so I created a test with `@Transactional` annotation. I do some setup queries and changes are visible within the tests which is expected result. However since my controller is also transactional it is unable to see changes performed before it was called (since they are not commited).

```
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class SpringContexstAwareTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private MyTestRepository testRepository

    def dbSetup() {
        testRepository.save(userWithId1)
    }

    def "some test"() {
        testRepository.findOne(1) //success
        mockMvc.perform(get("/user/1")).andReturn() //fails since there is no user with id 1 (the controller is also transactional)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have child transaction (controller) see changes of parent transaction(test db setup) in spring tests?

Comment: try `TransactionTemplate`

Comment: Are you passing any `TransactionDefinition` ?

Comment: @TheLostMind Thanks for replying. No

Comment: @user3364192 - Not even in the controller level?